# "Arrange by Kind" classifies .aux as Documents

Tags: finder

In my working folders I have several `.tex` files alongside `.pdf`, `.aux` and `.log`.

I like the idea that "Arrange by Kind" put `.tex` and `.pdf` on top because they are the files I usually need.
But it also classifies `.aux` as `Documents`, so `.aux` is on top.

Is there any chance to classify them as `Others`, just like `.log`?

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer right now, but this might help: https://superuser.com/questions/371892/osx-assign-extension-to-content-kind

Comment: @timothymh: That is a good starting point. Feel free to make this question duplicate.